# java reverseOrder() not working

Tags: java, sorting

I'd like to write a small program in Java 8 which prints out a list of characters in reverse lexicographic order. For example, "stack" should become "tskca". I entered this code:

```
public static void main (String[] args) {
    String input = "abc";
    char[] charArray = input.toCharArray();
    List<Character> charList = new ArrayList<Character>();
    for (char c : charArray) {
        charList.add(c);
    }
    System.out.println(charList.toString());
    charList.sort(Collections.reverseOrder());
    String output = charList.toString();
    System.out.println(input);
}
```

The output will be:

```
abc
```

I tried it with

```
    Collections.sort(charList, Collections.reverseOrder());
```

instead the other sorting line, same result. I looked up similar questions, but didn't find the same issue. Did I mess something up?

Comment: Quote: `System.out.println(input);`

Comment: On a side note: It's quite annoying that java doesn't provide comparator-like interfaces for primitive types..

Comment: Also: it's miles more efficient to use `Arrays.sort(charArray)`, and then reverse the resulting array.

Comment: @TobiasWeimer not especially; when was the last time you wanted to sort a primitive array by anything other than natural order (use `Arrays.sort`), or reverse natural order (use `Arrays.sort`, then reverse the array)?

Comment: @AndyTurner I have indeed had the case that I wanted to sort characters by case-insensitive order. Or for `int[]`, it might make sense to sort them by their absolute value.

Comment: @TobiasWeimer OK, I can see those cases. But I would suggest those use cases are rare enough that they just wouldn't carry their weight in the Java API.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just a little typo... Change

```
System.out.println(input);
```

to

```
System.out.println(output);
```

Comment: this isn't the whole problem. Try running your solution and you will see it still doesn't work

Comment: @bhspencer I ran it, it works perfectly.

Comment: @CardinalSystem [I ran it, it doesn't](https://ideone.com/xQbtSd). It prints the list, not the string of chars in reverse order.

Comment: It printed `[a, b, c]
[c, b, a]`. That is reverse lexicographic order.

Comment: @CardinalSystem it should print `cba`.

Comment: Ohhh, I see that now. My  edited answer prints `cba`.

Comment: Thanks! Such a trivial mistake. Man, I blew a job interview because of this :( :)

Comment: @AndyTurner Right, but from there it wasn't really difficult.

Comment: sad to hear that. but it happens to the best of us. i dont even want to think about how much time i spent debugging such stupid typos.. i recommend using intellij as an IDE. it would warn you, that `output` is assigned but never used

Comment: @LonelyNeuron I should have debugged it. Well, I used Eclipse, and it did warn me, but I guess I was too stressed out to pay enough attention.

Answer (score 3):

I think it helps to print the correct String ;)

```
System.out.println(output);
```

If you want it to print `cba` instead of `[c, b, a]`, than use `for-each`:

```
charList.stream().forEach(System.out::print);
```